# Clear parent state from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Parent component

```
const defaultState: State = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  inProgress: false
}

const LoginModal = (props: Props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

  const cleanUp = () => {
    setState(defaultState)
  }

  const onInputChange = (event, fieldName) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setState({...state, [fieldName]: event.target.value})
}

  return (
    <Modal
      title={<span className="login-modal-title">{t('modals.login.title')}</span>}
    >
      <div>
        <LoginForm email={state.email} password={state.password} inputChangeCallback={onInputChange} cleanUp={cleanUp}/>)}
      </div>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

and children component

```
const LoginForm = (props: Props) => {

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        props.login({
            email: props.email,
            password: props.password,
        callback: () => {
            showConfirmation('Success', 'You are successfully logged in.')
        },
        onError: () => {
          props.cleanUp();
        }
        });
    }

    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="loginForm">
            <Form.Item>
                <Input label={t('modals.login.emailPlaceholder')} value={props.email} onChange={e => props.inputChangeCallback(e, 'email')} />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>  
                <Input type="password" label={t('modals.login.passwordPlaceholder')} value={props.password} onChange={e => props.inputChangeCallback(e, 'password')} />
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    )
}
```

On form submit method 'login' is fired.
If this method returns error than it should fire cleanUp method in LoginModal component and clear state, but it doesn't.
Do you know why in LoginForm component input values are not cleared?

Comment: The child's `handleSubmit` calls `props.login`, but no such prop is provided by the parent. Either this example is incomplete, or your code simply throws an error.

Comment: props.login is a method from redux. It works fine. if I set console.log in cleanUp method in LoginModal component it's fired. The children fire parent cleanUp method correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the function passed to `onError` is called? Other than that there is nothing wrong with the code.

```js
const { useState } = React;
//fake login function that will call onError later
const login = ({ onError }) =>
  setTimeout(() => onError(), 500);
const defaultState = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  inProgress: false,
};

const LoginModal = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
  const cleanUp = () => {
    setState(defaultState);
  };
  const onInputChange = (event, fieldName) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setState({ ...state, [fieldName]: event.target.value });
  };
  return (
    <div
      title={
        <span className="login-modal-title">
          {'modals.login.title'}
        </span>
      }
    >
      <div>
        <LoginForm
          email={state.email}
          password={state.password}
          inputChangeCallback={onInputChange}
          cleanUp={cleanUp}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    login({
      email: props.email,
      password: props.password,
      callback: () => 88,
      onError: () => {
        props.cleanUp();
      },
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={props.email}
        onChange={(e) =>
          props.inputChangeCallback(e, 'email')
        }
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginModal />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```